# Automatically assigning unique values to #defines

Tags: objective-c, enums, c-preprocessor

I have a long list of `#define` statements (Objective-C) that are assigned unique integer values.

The actual values don't matter; they just have to be non-zero and unique.  The values are used to create `NSNumbers` and in switch statements.

For example:

```
#define FUNCTION_s   1
#define FUNCTION_a   7
#define FUNCTION_kk  3
```

Usage:

```
NSArray *array = @[ @(FUNCTION_s), @(FUNCTION_a) ];
// ...
switch ( val ) {
    case FUNCTION_kk:
        // code
    break;
}
```

I'd like to simplify the list so I don't have to worry about the actual numbers or accidentally using duplicate values.  I often rearrange the list for readability, so it's not always obvious which numbers I've already used.

Is there a way, similar to using an enum, that will automatically assign a unique value to each `#define`?

Comment: Why do they need to be `#define`s? As you even mention in the question, and trick14 replies below, this is crying out to be an `enum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enum.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FUNCTIONS) {
    FUNCTION_s = 1,
    FUNCTION_a,
    FUNCTION_kk,
};
```

FUNCTION_a will be 2 and kk will be 3. It's incremental.

```
FUNCTION val;
// set val

switch(val)
{
    // casese
}
```

Comment: I thought was possible, but I get errors wherever those FUNCTIONs are used.  E.g., this case statement `case FUNCTION_kk:` generates this error "Use of undeclared identifier 'FUNCTION_kk'".  So, I'm obviously not using the correct syntax.

Comment: @Jeff // Where did u declare the FUNCTIONS? I always use this coding style, but never had that problem. Can you add your code?

Comment: Based on your syntax example, I took a closer look at my code and realized the enum was in the wrong place (inside a method, where my #defines lived comfortably) and thus out of scope.  I moved it to the top, and it's working now.  Answered.  Thanks.